# Bootstrap 5 modal doesn't show

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

following the documentation I try to implement a modal when you click on a button. What I did is the following.Inside a form I have a button:

```
<div class="col-12 offset-md-10">  
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdropLive">   Launch static backdrop modal 
 </button> 
</div>
```

In the bottom of the code, over the scripts I have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdropLive" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLiveLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLiveLabel">Modal title</h1>
     <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>I will not close if you click outside of me. Don't even try to press escape key.</p>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The button appear correctly but when I click on it the modal doesn't show.
I have another modal for confirmation of logout and it works correctly. I'm using bootstrap 5.
Suggestions? Thanks

UPDATE: removing the -bs it works. Why this? I remember -bs is needed for bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted above is working fine. Check your HTML and CSS.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-12 offset-md-10">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdropLive"> Launch static backdrop modal
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdropLive" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLiveLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLiveLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>I will not close if you click outside of me. Don't even try to press escape key.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

You probably didn't include Bootstrap 5, but Bootstrap 4 into your project.

[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/):

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Mine is working if I remove the -bs from everywhere. How is it possible? I remember it is needed in bootstrap 5

Comment: I have these to scripts about bootstrap:

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    </script>

Comment: I edited my answer once again. You have to [download Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) if you want to use Bootstrap 5.